# Dynamically update cells after form submission

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a user list based on a code, simply put we have a system where every member of our school has an assigned code, with this code I can get their name and e-mail by making some regexes on our website (basically data mining).

The idea is to enter only this user code (let's say 0123456) and a script will get the data from the website and fill adjacent column values. The script must run on the *on form subit* trigger, so it's updated only when needed.

I've successfully implemented the data gathering system, but I'm struggling in the filling of the adjacent cells.

```
// this function is called when form is submitted
function onNewEntry(e)
{
  // get the code (cell 0 is the timestamp)
  userCode = e.values[1];

  // add values and return
  return e.values.concat(["name", "e-mail"]);
}
```

I expected the script to change the cells in columns C and D with "name" and "e-mail", but nothing happens. Can anybody advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function when triggered by on Form submit will write data in column C and D

(I used xx and yy just to illustrate)

```
function myFunction(e) {

var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];

var last = sh.getLastRow()

sh.getRange(last,3,1,2).setValues([['xx','yy']])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Range.setValues([Array]) is your solution. Note the 's' in setValues(...).

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)

Also, I haven't tested this, but I don't think the object (e) refers to the actual cells, but a copy of the submitted data. I think you'll need to open the sheet and get the range if you want to modify or append to the result.