# What do I change in the following code to identify already existing sheet and add data to it corresponding to data added in master sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[1]I have various sheets with the name of my clients in a spreadsheet. And I have one sheet where payments done by them are added using form. Now, I want this code to insert payment details into the clients' respective sheets by matching the sheet name to the name of client in payment details sheet.

[Sample worksheet for your reference](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NjWn_6ZfmkRLAJLf0zeBhuKlEP7vWRxOPCyFnRtTeVg/edit?usp=sharing)

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var master = ss.getSheetByName('Payment Details');
var sheets = ss.getSheets(); // number of sheets
var colWidth = master.getLastColumn();
function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Copy selected Rows to sheets", functionName: "copyRowsOnConditionV2"},];
  ss.addMenu("Copy functions",menuEntries);// custom menu
}
function copyRowsOnConditionV2() {
  var sheetNames = [];// array of existing sheet names
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();// number of sheets
  for(s=0;s<sheets.length;++s){sheetNames.push(sheets[s].getName())};
  ss.getActiveSelection().setBackground('#ffffbb'); 
  var selectedfirstRow = ss.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  var selectedHeigth = ss.getActiveSelection().getHeight()
  var selectedFullRange = master.getRange(selectedfirstRow,1,selectedHeigth,colWidth);
  var data = selectedFullRange.getValues();
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
if(data[n][2].length<60){
  // Check if there is a sheet with this name already (uses names without the space)
  if (sheetNames.indexOf(data[n][2])) { 
    ss.insertSheet(data[n][2]) // Insert a new sheet WITH THE SPACE
    sheetNames.push(data[n][2]) // Add new sheet name to array of sheet names
  }
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName(data[n][2]);//find the destination sheet
  Logger.log(data[n][2])
  // Find the last column with data
  var lastcol = dest.getLastColumn();
  // Set the range to the next col over
  dest.getRange(31, (lastcol +1)).setValue(data[n][3]);
  dest.getRange(32, (lastcol +1)).setValue(data[n][4]);
  var destRange = dest.getRange('h33').setFormula("=h30-h31-i31-j31-k31-l31-m31-n31");
    }
  }
}
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGmwk.png [Getting this error when running the code] I want it to add the data to the same sheet instead of creating new one.

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659998/dynamically-update-cells-after-form-submission) to update cells after form submission. `Range.setValues([Array])` also might be your solution. Note the `s` in [`setValues(...)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)).

Comment: @abielita no man! Not what I was looking for. The below code does it for me. works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was not completely sure what you wanted with the spaces - or didnt want. Commented out are the lines to use *with* spaces. Also for the `d30,d31,d32` empty column question, you can use [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastColumn()) to find the last column with data and add a `+1` for the range's column position to move over to the next empty column.

```
function copyRowsOnConditionV2() {
  var sheetNames = [];// array of existing sheet names
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();// number of sheets
  for(s=0;s<sheets.length;++s){sheetNames.push(sheets[s].getName())};

  ss.getActiveSelection().setBackground('#ffffbb'); 
 ...
  var data = selectedFullRange.getValues();

  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n][2].length<60){
      // Check if there is a sheet with this name already (uses names without the space)
      if (sheetNames.indexOf(data[n][2]) == -1) { 

        ss.insertSheet(data[n][2]); // Insert a new sheet WITH THE SPACE
        sheetNames.push(data[n][2]); // Add new sheet name to array of sheet names

        // Apply pending Spreadsheet changes
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }

      var dest = ss.getSheetByName(data[n][2]);//find the destination sheet

      // Find the last column with data
      var lastcol = dest.getLastColumn();

      // Set the range to the next col over
      dest.getRange(30, (lastcol +1)).setValue(data[n][3]);
      dest.getRange(31, (lastcol +1)).setValue(data[n][4]);
      dest.getRange(32, (lastcol +1)).setFormula("=d29-d30-e30-f30");

   ...

    }
  }
}
```

**edit** Updated code to reflect that spaces were wanted

Comment: I wanted to have spaces in the sheet names like "New Sheet" while previously I was getting "NewSheet". Now I have started getting error that the sheet already exists. I want it to add the data to the existing sheet. What do I need to change?

Comment: updated the code to keep the spaces and `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` to make sure the `sheetNames` gets updated